# I dont see the Visual Studio option in my azure portal

Tags: azure-functions

Visual Studio option is not available in the template options on the Azure portal while creating a new function. I shared the screenshot for the same. I selected .net as runtime while creating Function Application.

[image]

I was expecting to get VS option while creating new function

Comment: You can directly create a function by clicking template in azure portal for C# Or you can create a function in c# and deploy it to azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

If you select Dot Net as Runtime stack you will not be able to see Visual studio option over there as you can write your code directly after creating azure function in Portal as below:

[image]

Or you can create a function in Visual Studio and then you can deploy it back to Azure Portal

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio?tabs=in-process) to create locally and publishing it to azure.